# Pourquoi "notamment" prend-il deux "m"?

Tags: orthographe

"Notamment" vient du latin "noto, notare" et "mens, mentis", pourquoi double-t-on le "m"?

Par exemple dans "lentement" qui a une étymologie proche s'écrit avec un seul "m".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parce que l'adverbe est formé à partir du participe présent : *notant* + *-ment* → *notamment*. La règle générale de formation des adverbes est de partir d'un adjectif (souvent mais pas toujours un participe présent). Si l'adjectif au masculin singulier se termine par le suffixe *-ant* ou *-ent*, l'adverbe se termine par *-amment* ou *-emment*. S'il se termine par une voyelle, on ajoute *-ment*. Sinon (et quelquefois aussi lorsque le masculin se termine par une voyelle) on prend l'adjectif au féminin singulier et on ajoute *-ment*. Exemples :

- *notant* → *notamment*, *bruyant* → *bruyamment*
- *apparent* → *apparemment*, *différent* → *différemment*
- *facile* → *facilement*, *absolu* → *absolument*
- *grand* (m.) → *grande* (f.) → *grandement*, *gai* (m.) → *gaie* (f.) → *gaiement*

On remarque que lorsque l'adverbe est dérivé du féminin, il se termine par *-ement* avec un seul M, et se prononce [-ə.mɑ̃] avec un E muet avant la dernière syllabe (ou un E qui ne se prononce pas du tout comme dans *gaiement* [ge.mɑ̃]). Par contre, les adverbes dérivés d'un adjectif en *-ent* se terminent par *-emment* avec deux M, prononcé [-amɑ̃]. On ne peut pas distinguer *-emment* de *-amment* par la prononciation, pas plus que *-ent* de *-ant*.

La raison des deux M est que le premier fait partie du suffixe intermédiaire de l'adjectif (c'est un N qui se transforme en M parce qu'il est suivi d'un autre M) et le deuxième fait partie du suffixe *-ment*. À l'époque où l'orthographe du français s'est normalisée, on prononçait l'avant-dernière syllabe avec une voyelle nasale : *notamment* [no.tɑ̃.mɑ̃], *apparamment* [ap.pa.ʁɑ̃.mɑ̃] (ou [ap.pa.ʁɛ̃.mɑ̃] ?).

Le français étant le français, il y a des exceptions. La plupart des adjectifs en *-ant* ou *-ent* sont construits en ajoutant le suffixe *-ant* ou *-ent* à une racine, mais *lent* est directement la racine *lent-* sans suffixe. C'est pour cela que son adverbe suit la forme féminin + *-ent* et non racine (= masculin - *-ent*) + *-emment*. Il ne me vient pas à l'esprit d'autre exception similaire (il y a d'autres adjectifs où *-ent* fait partie de la racine en français, mais pas en latin, comme *prudent* de *[prudens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prudens#la)* de *provideo* + *-ens* ou *innocent* de *[innocens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/innocens#la)* de *in-* + *noceo* + *-ens*).

Pour une histoire un peu plus détaillée (j'ai simplifié un peu dans ma réponse), voir par exemple [*Les suffixes -amment et -emment*](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/adv-ment.html)

Comment: C'est une réponse très complète est d'une grande qualité, merci beaucoup